# Weblogic 11g: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND cvc-complex-type.2.4b

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, ear, weblogic11g

I have the following error installing an EAR application on weblogic server 10.3.6 for developers:

```
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: tracking-mode@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee in element session-config@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

How to solve this? It would be good also a way in order to skip validation.

The server log reports the following message:

```
####<6-ott-2017 11.19.37 CEST> <Error> <J2EE> <miopc> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1507281577963> <BEA-160197> <Unable to load descriptor /Users/mypc/weblogic/domain/servers/myserver/tmp/.appmergegen_1507281576131_MyApp.ear/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/web.xml of module MyApp.war.
The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: tracking-mode@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee in element session-config@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

Comment: Your web.xml file is incorrect.
As tracking-mode was introduced with Servlet 3.0 check that you web app is well configured for Servlet 3 : 
`<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`

Comment: I thought the same, but can you explain to me why the same ear is correctly  installed in the release server? Same ear and same version of weblogic...